# ElasticSearch in Magento2 Database

Tags: database, elasticsearch, magento2.4

Without to much backstory:
I am trying to configure elasticsearch port inside the database.
However, I can simply not find the table which holds the elastic search properties.
Can anyone help me out here?

Going trough the backend is not gonna be a solution, it has to go trough database.

Comment: I think we need a bit more `backstory` than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find the Catalog Search settings in the backend.

```
Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search
```

Under the Catalog Search, you'll see the below settings.

```
Search Engine
Elasticsearch Server Hostname
Elasticsearch Server Port
```

and some other parameters too.

But if you wish to update the values from the database you can run the below SQL query in your DB tool or MySQL console.

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE '%catalog/search/%';
```

Then update the fields with the appropriate values.

Happy Coding!